# Does boot-repair damage windows?

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, grub2, windows, boot-repair

I used a partion manager on Windows which told me to reinit GRUB. I was going to do this using boot-repair but I read that it might damage my Windows dual boot? Is it safe?

Comment: What if I were to use automatic repair?

Comment: How do I re add Windows??

Comment: sudo update-grub should find your windows partion.

Comment: @Jeff : My experience so far is that if Windows is UEFI and Ubuntu is BIOS, grub will not boot Windows. "sudo update-grub" should do it if both are the same mode.